# Oracle : select maximum value from different columns of the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8i

The whole question is pretty much in the title. For each row of the table I'd like to select the maximum of a subset of columns.

For example, from this table

```
name m1 m2 m3 m4
A    1  2  3  4
B    6  3  4  5
C    1  5  2  1
```

the result would be

```
name max
A    4
B    6
C    5
```

The query must be compatible oracle 8i.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Given this test data ...

```
SQL> select *
  2  from your_table
  3  /

NAME         M1         M2         M3         M4
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A             1          2          3          4
B             6          3          4          5
C             1          5          2          1

SQL>
```

... a straightforward GREATEST() call will give the desired result:

```
SQL> select name
  2          , greatest(m1, m2, m3, m4) as the greatest_m
  3  from your_table
  4  /

NAME THE_GREATEST_M
---- --------------
A                 4
B                 6
C                 5

SQL>
```

Note that `greatest()` will return NULL if any of the arguments are null. If this is a problem then use `nvl()` to provide a default value which won't distort the outcome. For instance, if no values can be negative....

```
SQL> select name
  2          , greatest(nvl(m1,0), nvl(m2,0), nvl(m3,0), nvl(m4,0)) as the greatest_m
  3  from your_table
  4  /

NAME THE_GREATEST_M
---- --------------
A                 4
B                 6
C                 5

SQL>
```

Comment: Just a warning that, if any of the columns is NULL, greatest will always return NULL

Answer (score 24):

Use `GREATEST` but also handle possible `NULL`'s

```
SELECT name, GREATEST(NVL(m1,0), NVL(m2,0), NVL(m3,0), NVL(m4,0)) AS "Max"
FROM yourtable
```

Input:

```
name m1 m2 m3 m4
A    1  2  3  4
B    6  3  4  5
C    1  5  2  1
```

Output:

```
NAME Max
A    4
B    6
C    5
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae268/7/0

Input:

```
name m1 m2   m3 m4
A    1  2    3  null
B    6  null 4  5
C    1  5    2  1
```

Output:

```
NAME Max
A    3
B    6
C    5
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1c46/1/0